# How to use TortoiseHG in Nautilus?

Tags: nautilus, mercurial

I'm used to TortoiseHg on Windows. I tried

```
apt-get install tortoisehg tortoisehg-nautilus
```

But after the installation I still can't use it by typing

```
tortoisehg
```

In the terminal or in the launcher, nor can I right click in a folder and see it in the context menu.

What mercurial GUI works with Unity? If tortoiseHg does, how to use it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can run TortoiseHG using command `thg` (or `hgtk` in older versions), usually in the directory with Mercurial repo.

To use Nautilus plugin, Nautilus must be restarted first by logging out or executing `nautilus -q`. You should see TortoiseHG in context menu and File menu then.

Answer (score 2):

If you've literally typed the above in, you've got the 'g' and 'h' swapped in your `apt-get` line:

```
tortoisegh-nautilus
```

should be

```
tortoisehg-nautilus
```

Answer (score 0):

If it doesn't show in 13.04 and beyond, I managed to install it rather easily by using the tortoisehg ppa:

```
sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:tortoisehg-ppa/releases
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install mercurial tortoisehg
```

Answer (score 0):

At Ubuntu 13.04 after installing from PPA if you cant get the tortoise menu in nautilus and if you have something like this on your .xsession-errors file at home directory:

(nautilus:2750): Nautilus-Python-WARNING **: g_module_open libpython failed: /usr/lib/libpython2.7.so.1.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
compiz (core) - Info: Unity is fully supported by your hardware.
compiz (core) - Info: Unity is fully supported by your hardware.
compiz (core) - Info: Starting plugin: opengl
ImportError: could not import gobject (error was: '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpyglib-gi-2.0-python2.7.so.0: undefined symbol: _Py_ZeroStruct')

Maybe this could help you:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/tortoisehg/+bug/1202823

Good luck