# Tortoisehg integration within nautilus3.6.3 in ubuntu 13.04

Tags: nautilus, mercurial

I installed ubuntu 13.04 (with Gnome nautilus 3.6.3) and tried to install tortoise workbench using these commands in he terminal

```
sudo apt-get install mercurial tortoisehg tortoisehg-nautilus 
nautilus -q
```

I can launch the tortoise workbench from the terminal using *thg* but

- I do not have the context menu when right-clicking on folder in nautilus
- I do not have icon overlay (green or red discs on he folder)

following a suggestion made [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/48382/how-to-use-tortoisehg-in-nautilus) I tried

```
sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:tortoisehg-ppa/releases 
sudo apt-get update  
sudo apt-get install mercurial tortoisehg
```

Without more success.

Has anyone got the context menu and the icon overlay working with Ubuntu 13.04?

Comment: I have the same problem and the apt-get-repository command did not fix it. You might consider clicking on "[this bug affects me too](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/tortoisehg/+bug/1202823)"

Comment: Did you reboot the system? Nautilus sometimes needs to be restarted for it to work.

Comment: i am also facing the same issue.